# How to retrieve data offline in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, offline-caching

In my application i want to save some data to be accessed while being offline, This data contain the text as well images so can any one suggest how can i make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could load your web content using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and store the contents of the response locally to the file system or in an sqlite database.  For persistent storage, you can use Core Data or [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)